# Macbook Pro 2018 13-inch screen protector

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

Do I need a screen protector for long term usage because after 1 year of purchase , I have started noticing keyboard impressions on my macbook screen which are impossible to remove and also leave very tiny black dots on screen. Which is the best screen protector for Macbook Pro that won't damage the screen if removed?
I am really worried about the screen for long term usage.

Comment: That's the protective coating that's coming off, not the keyboard leaving impressions.  That glass needs to be replaced. They used to have a program for this, but it may have expired by  now.

Comment: Will putting a screen guard save it from further damage?

Comment: I have used the thin piece of foam that laptops ship with between the screen and keyboard when the laptop is closed to help protect from that kind of issue. I suppose a piece of Chamois cut to the right size might help with that...